# Export method from imported module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

Consider the following example where I import a module with an **indefinite** number of items:

```js
import * as module from './module.js';

const something = () => {
  // Also doing something with other methods from the imported module.
  return module.method1() * 2;
}


export {
  something as default,
  module.method2 as method2 // THIS DOES NOT WORK!!
}
```

I want to export `method2` from the imported module, but I can't make it work.

Also I don't benefit from destructuring because I also use an indefinite number of methods in the code (not pictured in the example).

How can I achieve this?
Can I export it directly without assigning the `method2` to a new variable before exporting?

Also worth nothing that I might use the same method name or not.
Does this influence the outcome, apart from using `x as y`?

Comment: Not sure, but did you tried it like this `export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;`

Comment: @Ifaruki, thanks for the suggestion, but like I mentioned, I will not benefit from destructuring in my use case. I very much prefer to load the entire module.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a separate

```
export { method2 } from './module.js';
// or
export { method2 as methodAlias } from './module.js';
// or with a local identifier:
import { method2 } from './module.js';
export { method2 }
```

If you only want to refer to the `module` namespace object, and not repeat the imported module specifier, then yes you need to create an extra variable to export it.

```
export const method2 = module.method2;
// or
export const { method2 } = module;
```